# How to create backup of ms access using c# code?

Tags: c#, ms-access

```
 private void Backup()
    {
        string dbFileName = "Clients.accdb";
        string CurrentDatabasePath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, dbFileName);
        string backTimeStamp = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(dbFileName) + Path.GetExtension(dbFileName);
        string destFileName = backTimeStamp + dbFileName;
        FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string PathtobackUp = fbd.SelectedPath.ToString();
            destFileName = Path.Combine(PathtobackUp, destFileName);
            File.Copy(CurrentDatabasePath, destFileName, true);
            MessageBox.Show("successful Backup! ");
        }
    }
```

my database is in D drive, I have this method to backup ms access database, But this is not taking backup when I am add some data in database.

Comment: Do you have access application closed when you're creating your backup ? Also are all data stored just in access file or are you accessing other storage as well (MS SQL server, etc.) ?

Comment: database is ms access and It is closed when backup

Comment: `string backTimeStamp = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(dbFileName) + Path.GetExtension(dbFileName);` doesn't seem to be correct. You recreate the same dbFileName, no timestamp here

Comment: May be, can you correct the code?